# How to check the result from AWSTask

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am calling an API from AWS, whose model isn't with me right now, I want to know what JSON it returns in response to a request so that I can build the model and use it. Is there a way to print the JSON ? I tried printing result property of task but its empty ( may be its obvious), is there a way to do this ?

Comment: You can download the model from the AWS APIGateway Console where you created the API. Is that not possible? Otherwise you can learn more about AWSTask from here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/aws-aysnchronous-tasks-for-ios.html